# align div and buttons and keep modal functioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I'm new to `CSS` so this is probably a really basic question but I've searched everywhere and am completely stuck.

I have a `div` and two buttons.  One button opens a modal.  This much is working.

I can't get the `div` to align vertically on top of my buttons.  When I put everything in a new, parent div, the modal/buttons stack on top of one another and stop functioning.

My code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/k3eL99ub/

```
 <div id="page1" class="landing-page">
  <a id="link-lp"></a>
  <div class="logo-sketch">Logo here</div>
  <button id="about-button">about</button>
  <button id="work-button">work</button>
  <div id="about-modal">
    <div id="about-modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <p class="about-text">stuff here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.landing-page {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo-sketch {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

button {
  display: inline;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 10%;
}

.about-button {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

button.work-button {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 50px;
}


/*about modal styling*/

#about-modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

#about-modal-content {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
}

.close {
  color: #000;
  float: right;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You want logo to be on top of your buttons ?

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 yes, I want the logo on top and the buttons underneath.  The two buttons should be next to each other the way they are now.

Comment: I made jsfiddle for you is that what you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more ways to do this the easiest it to change your `HTML` structure. for example like this:

```
  <div class="logo-sketch">Logo here</div>
  <div id="page1" class="landing-page">
      <a id="link-lp"></a>

      <button id="about-button">about</button>
      <button id="work-button">work</button>
      <div id="about-modal">
        <div id="about-modal-content">
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
          <p class="about-text">stuff here</p>  
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is JSFindle https://jsfiddle.net/987sp7ex/

Comment: thank you!  do you know why the 'about' button modal stops working? do I need to change the js as well?

Comment: oh weird it was working on mine :/  I'll keep plugging away, thanks!

Comment: Choose my answer if it helped you :)

Comment: the code you shared is not working for me :/  the logo appeared below the div with the buttons.  i put the whole page code into the jsfiddle now if you could look again: https://jsfiddle.net/k3eL99ub/3/

Comment: Just change `grid-row` here is new fiddle with working solution https://jsfiddle.net/m2o0j9bo/

Comment: thank you for your help but this is still not quite right.  the logo should be right above the buttons with the same colorful background.  right now it is above the colorful area.  do i need a new div for the buttons?

Comment: Here is new fiddle for you  https://jsfiddle.net/114mnt06/   Is this what you want ?

Comment: @user7875185 No problem, happy to help :)